# ¿Porqué sólo se muestra la página principal de mi aplicación web con AngularJS en los motores de búsqueda?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, .htaccess, google-search-console

Tengo un problema: por alguna razón, que desconozco, sólo se muestra la página principal de mi aplicación web ([geekmox.com](http://geekmox.com)) con AngularJS en los motores de búsqueda. Si sirve de algo, utilizo el .htaccess para redireccionar a una página estática en PHP los enlaces de los artículos, para que los crawlers saquen de ahí los metadatos -no se si de ahí venga el error, pero creo que no. El problema es ese, que sólo se muestra la página principal en los motores de búsqueda, algún consejo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando la araña del buscador llega a tu página no puede ver los enlaces porque estos se generan mediante JavaScript y AngularJS.

Aunque las arañas de los buscadores, y específicamente la de Google, se supone que admiten JavaScript y que ejecutarán el códuigo como un navegador normal esto no siempre es cierto.

Google recomienda que tu aplicación web siga la estrategia de [mejora progresiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mejora_progresiva) para facilitar el trabajo de su araña.

También comentan que el rendimiento es importante.

Puedes ver tú mismo sus [recomendaciones](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html), en inglés.

Por último, quizá te sirva usar las herramientas de webmaster de Google para comprobar como ve Google tu página: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468 (en inglés). Esto quizá te ayude a depurar el problema con tu página.